# Intuition behind why being integral over a ring is important

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm currently in an algebraic geometry class and many of our proofs and lemmas have to do with some element $w$ being integral over a ring. The proofs end up working out, but I have trouble understanding why this is an important property to have (being the root of a monic polynomial) and what intuition I should have behind it. For example, consider:

$R \subset F, \space L=Frac(R). Let \space w \in I$ be algebraic over $R$. Then $\exists \space p \in R,p≠0$ s.t. $pw$ is integral over R.

Comment: You might find the answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1504/what-is-the-geometric-meaning-of-integral-closure) helpful.

Comment: @Stahl That's the geometric meaning of being integrally closed, not the geometric importance of integrality. OP: you should recall that integral+finite type implies finite. In fact, integrality it something like "element-by-element finiteness". So, if you're happy with why finiteness is a desirable property, maybe integrality makes sense to you too. If not, I can try to provide more detail.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I agree! That's why I left it as a potentially helpful comment for intuition and not an answer to the original question ;)

Comment: @AlexYoucis Could you provide more detail please?